# Redirect that starts with a?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I need to have a redirect done to a site I have that is a 404 error.
Redirects are done in a .htaccess file for Joomla. This is what I have currently:

```
redirect 301 /?view=category&id=12:bestfriend&Itemid=946&start=20 http://www.mysite.com
```

But it doesn't redirect because it starts with a "?".
Any ideas? I have a number amount of these like this - not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=category&id=12:bestfriend&Itemid=946&start=20 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com/? [R=301,L]
```